# What is the proper way to preview a file (image or pdf) using active storage?

Tags: rails-activestorage

I am trying to preview a PDF file and an image file I have uploaded:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :resourceable, :polymorphic => true
   has_one_attached :file
end
```

I tried to use .preview and .representation methods to show the preview of uploaded image or pdf as thumbnail.

1. using preview(), results in the following error:

```
@document.file.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100])

ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError: ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError
```

2. using representation(), image_tag is unable to resolve the image url from the ActiveStorage::Variant object resulting in the following error:

```
>>> image_tag(@document.file.representation(resize: '500x500'))

ArgumentError: Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<ActiveStorage::Variant:0x00007fe39e809768>
```

`document.file.representable?` and `document.file.previewable?` in some documentation. Wonder what does these methods do? I could get representable as true sometimes but previewable false.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 5.2 the `image_tag` helper required you to pass a url. Before it would guess as to what was passed.

To pass the url from your active storage variant do something like this:

```
image_tag(main_app.rails_representation_url(
    @document.file.variant(resize: '500x500'))
) if @document.file.attached?
```

Images are not previewable according to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html), PDF's are.

To check if the document has a preview available use the `previewable?` method:

```
image_tag(main_app.rails_representation_url(
    @document.try(@document.previewable? ? :preview : :variant, resize: '500x500')
) if @document.file.attached?
```